# PostgreSQL: Sequential scan despite having indexes

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have the following two tables.

- person_addresses
- address_normalization

The `person_addresses` table has a field named `address_id` as the primary key and `address_normalization` has the corresponding field `address_id` which has an index on it.

Now, when I explain the following query, I see a sequential scan.

```
SELECT
    count(*)
FROM
    mp_member2.person_addresses pa
JOIN mp_member2.address_normalization an ON
    an.address_id = pa.address_id
WHERE
    an.sr_modification_time >= 1550692189468;

-- Result: 2654
```

Please refer to the following screenshot.

[image]

You see that there is a sequential scan after the hash join. I'm not sure I understand this part; why would a sequential scan follow a hash join.

And as seen in the query above, the set of records returned is also low.

Is this expected behaviour or am I doing something wrong?

---

**Update #1:** I also have indices on the `sr_modification_time` fields of both the tables

**Update #2:** Full execution plan

```
Aggregate  (cost=206944.74..206944.75 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=2807.844..2807.844 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=4629 read=82217
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=2881.95..206825.15 rows=47836 width=0) (actual time=0.775..2807.160 rows=2654 loops=1)
        Hash Cond: (pa.address_id = an.address_id)
        Buffers: shared hit=4629 read=82217
        ->  Seq Scan on person_addresses pa  (cost=0.00..135924.93 rows=4911993 width=8) (actual time=0.005..1374.610 rows=4911993 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=4588 read=82217
        ->  Hash  (cost=2432.05..2432.05 rows=35992 width=18) (actual time=0.756..0.756 rows=1005 loops=1)
              Buckets: 4096  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 41kB
              Buffers: shared hit=41
              ->  Index Scan using mp_member2_address_normalization_mod_time on address_normalization an  (cost=0.43..2432.05 rows=35992 width=18) (actual time=0.012..0.424 rows=1005 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (sr_modification_time >= 1550692189468::bigint)
                    Buffers: shared hit=41
Planning time: 0.244 ms
Execution time: 2807.885 ms
```

**Update #3:**  I tried with a newer timestamp and it used an index scan.

```
EXPLAIN (
    ANALYZE
    , buffers
    , format TEXT
) SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    mp_member2.person_addresses pa
JOIN mp_member2.address_normalization an ON
    an.address_id = pa.address_id
WHERE
    an.sr_modification_time >= 1557507300342;

-- count: 1364
```

Query Plan:

```
Aggregate  (cost=295.48..295.49 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=2.770..2.770 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=1404
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=4.89..295.43 rows=19 width=0) (actual time=0.038..2.491 rows=1364 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=1404
        ->  Index Scan using mp_member2_address_normalization_mod_time on address_normalization an  (cost=0.43..8.82 rows=14 width=18) (actual time=0.009..0.142 rows=341 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (sr_modification_time >= 1557507300342::bigint)
              Buffers: shared hit=14
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on person_addresses pa  (cost=4.46..20.43 rows=4 width=8) (actual time=0.004..0.005 rows=4 loops=341)
              Recheck Cond: (address_id = an.address_id)
              Heap Blocks: exact=360
              Buffers: shared hit=1390
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_mp_member2_person_addresses_address_id  (cost=0.00..4.46 rows=4 width=0) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=4 loops=341)
                    Index Cond: (address_id = an.address_id)
                    Buffers: shared hit=1030
Planning time: 0.214 ms
Execution time: 2.816 ms
```

Comment: The sequential scan is part of the hash join, not after it.  Read the execution plan outwards from the most indented part.  The index scan is the first thing.

Comment: @Jeremy - I understand; my question is that why isn't it an index scan?

Comment: How many rows has each table?

Comment: The optimizer can't determine that the condition on `address_normalization.sr_modification_time` (why is a column called "time" a number?) also reduced the rows in `person_addresses`. It expects all rows to be returned from that join, that's why it chooses the seq scan. If you have a modification "number" on `person_address` as well you should include that in the where clause if possible. I wouldn't be surprised if a more modern Postgres actually does a better job with that

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Most liked is a unix time using numbers of seconds  since Jan 01 1970. https://www.unixtimestamp.com/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `sr_modification_time` is an int8 because it stores the unix epoch

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: what's the advantage over a proper `timestamp` (it can't be readability)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I think you are correct; it cannot be determined that that particular condition on address_normalization.sr_modification_time reduces the rows in person_addresses. I tried with a newer timestamp and it used an index scan.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I dont have idea but when you send date type using JavaScript he converts it to unix timestamp, and that cause a lot of issues when you need convert it back to datetime to store in your model :/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think the idea was to make the join conditions simpler; in this case, simple integer comparison. Also, we only use these timestamps for getting incremental deltas; we don't get it from the source, you can say these are audit fields.

Comment: @BileshGanguly: a timestamp comparison is also a simple integer comparison

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yeah, I know; it is better to keep timestamps as timestamps. But, currently, it is what it is.

Answer (score 0):

That is the expected behavior because you don't have index for `sr_modification_time` so after create the hash join db has to scan the whole set to check each row for the `sr_modification_time` value

You should create:

- index for `(sr_modification_time)`
- or  composite index for `(address_id , sr_modification_time )`

Comment: I'm sorry. I should have mentioned but both `sr_modification_time` fields have indices on them.

Comment: doh **facepalm**

Comment: In that case, if result is too small, db optimizer decide the overhead for using index is too much and  then just perform a full scan. Try with a composite index to see what you get.

Comment: I added the index - `CREATE INDEX idx_addr_id_mod_time ON mp_member2.address_normalization (address_id, sr_modification_time)` and explained the query again. It gave me the exact same result.